# Changing customer_id in the vault with braintree ruby sdk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, braintree

I have a rails app with `gem 'braintree'`.

Documentation:

https://developers.braintreepayments.com/ios+ruby/reference/request/credit-card/create
https://developers.braintreepayments.com/ios+ruby/reference/response/customer

I would like to change the way I store customer ids in the vault. (say, from `"BT_#{id}"` to `"SOME_OTHER_KEY_BT#{id}"`)

I would like to keep the existing cards each customer have in the vault.

Two approaches:

- **Updating existing customer ids** in the vault. The problem is that I don't find a way to just `update` ([doc](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/ios+ruby/reference/request/customer/update)) the customer, because I cannot specify the parameter `customer_id`. This parameter is used for reference, not as a value you specify to update.
- **Re-creating all customers** in the vault. The problem with that is that I would need to re-add every customer card info, and I don't have all the information needed (such as the card numbers) to re-submit the info.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>I work at Braintree. If you have more questions, please [get in touch with our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

The general suggestion in cases like this, is that you really shouldn't care what the Braintree customer ID is; you should store it along with your own customer ID in your database so you can map between the two. For all other purposes other than communicating with Braintree, you should use your own ID.

Comment: The point of my question is that we have **existing** customer ids in the vault, and I'd like to change those in the vault without changing their credit card info. Because this is not possible, I think I will just store the the ids in a `braintree_customer_id` field, like you suggest. So that I can make it compatible with old customer ids (by just setting setting the old ids to their current value in the vault)